# C# Cannot access non-static member field in static context, without actually being in static context

Tags: c#, static

Can anyone explain why I get the error
"Cannot access non-static field wtf in static context, even though I am NOT in a static context.

I get the error on the line "public int variable = wtf.queuePosition;"

```
class Test
{

    public Test wtf = new Test();
    public int variable = wtf.queuePosition;

    private int queuePosition;
    public Test()
    {
        queuePosition = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: wtf is an instance of the Test class - the one I have shown the code for :)

Comment: You can't initialize one field from the value of a different field in the field initializer. You need to move that code to the constructor. "Static context" simply means you're forbidden from accessing instance members.

Comment: A field initializer _is_ a static context: you cannot assign a member as you are in `public int variable = wtf.queuePosition;`

Comment: If you want to initialize variable, you'll have to do it in the constructor (what are you trying to achieve exactly?)

Comment: So Test is creating a Test.  You do know that would be an infinite loop even if it did compile.  WTF are you trying to do?

Comment: This is not an acutal problem... I am trying to understand why the error occurs. In terms of code - this is horrible. I was wondering why it says I am in a static context even though nothing in the class is static :)

Comment: static member != static context and as stuard commented, a field initializer (public int variable = wtf.queuePosition;) is a static context

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> though I am NOT in a static context.

The initialization of instance member variables is done before the code of your constructor is executed. At this time, there is still no `this` reference.

So I'm afraid your wrong. From the point of view of the compiler, you *are* in a static context.

From the [C# specification (17.4.5.2 Instance field initialization)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf):

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference 
>   this in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a variable initializer to reference any instance member through a simple-name.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the variable to the value of a property within another variable.  Your variable wtf is the non-static, however the variable assignment within a class is static.  So the assignment, 'public int variable = wtf.queuePosition;', is within a static context.

One obvious reason this is not allowed is shown within your example.  Your code would have a stack overflow exception real quickly.  As each instance of Test is newing up another instance of Test, which will new up another ...